# How to disable Alt + [F, E, V, ...] menu shortcuts in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to use some of the predefined menu shortcuts (Alt+F for **F**ile) in intellij idea.
Just defining the shortcut in the keymap doesn't override them.

Thanks

Comment: Settings/Appearance & Behavior/Appearance/Disable Mnemonics in Menu

Comment: Thank You @BohuslavBurghardt

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can disable the shortcuts here:

Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> Disable Mnemonics in Menu

Comment: @Cosmo same for Idea 2019.1 Seem like a bug.
Try closing and reopening after applying the settings. Worked for me

Comment: Worked for me in PyCharm & PHPStorm, but only after closing+opening the IDE.

Comment: Did not even work after restarting IDE for me. PhpStorm 2021.1.4